# Finding small-signal SPICE model output resistance of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, spice

I am using the level-8 SPICE model shown below.

g_ds_pmos = 0.0001845 => rds_pmos = 5420

I get r_ds very small from regular derivative. How can I get my ro from the SPICE model?

SPICE model:
https://sanjayvidhyadharan.in/Downloads/tsmc_180_nm/tsmc018.lib

T58F SPICE BSIM3 VERSION 3.1 PARAMETERS
*

- SPICE 3f5 Level 8, Star-HSPICE Level 49, UTMOST Level 8

Spice model manual:
https://class.ece.uw.edu/cadta/hspice/chapter_16.pdf

[image]

Comment: I can only find the small-signal equations for a LEVEL1 MOSFET.  Fortunately, some SPICE packages can spit out the small-signal parameters when doing an `.op` analysis.  Here is an example when using LTspice: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evpgv.png

Comment: Hello Ste,my LTSPICE only gives me currents an voltages.
what could be done to get Gds also?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the SPICE Error Log (CTRL+L).